# Find subsets of words - python itertools pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

Using Python, I am trying to create list of word stems 4 and 5 characters long to use in Scrabble-like games. From what I gather, I should be using itertools, but I'm stuck on how to combine it with Pandas (I have a csv-file with all the words).

I have tried to use Pandas and Itertools using what I've found in previous threads and have come up with the following which returns an error:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
import pandas as pd

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(4))

data = {'A':['hammers','hampering','hamburger']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['subset 4ch'] = df.apply(lambda row : powerset(row['A']), axis=1)
```

My desired output in the subset column for "hammers":
hamm, amme, mmer etc + hmrs, aers, etc.

How do I achieve this?

The end product would be a ranking of each possible stem and the words they appear in. I can see that my function is creating tuples, is this the most desirable with my desired end product in mind?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error do you run into? I've tried your code and it doesn't raise any error

Comment: When I go to view the df, the 'subset 4ch' return the following: <itertools.chain object at 0x0000019A7B213448>

Comment: That is not an error, it just says that it is returning an iterator https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator if you want to see what's inside the iterator just return it as a list: return list(chain ...), your code works just fine ;)

Comment: Oh, cool - thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return [''.join(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(4, 5))] 

df['subset 4ch'] = df.apply(lambda row : powerset(row['A']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A           subset 4ch
0   hammers     [hamm, hame, hamr, hams, hame, hamr, hams, hae...
1   hampering   [hamp, hame, hamr, hami, hamn, hamg, hape, hap...
2   hamburger   [hamb, hamu, hamr, hamg, hame, hamr, habu, hab...
```

And if you don't want the output words within a list:

```
return ", ".join([''.join(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(4, 5))])

    A           subset 4ch
0   hammers     hamm, hame, hamr, hams, hame, hamr, hams, haer...
1   hampering   hamp, hame, hamr, hami, hamn, hamg, hape, hapr...
2   hamburger   hamb, hamu, hamr, hamg, hame, hamr, habu, habr...
```